# AngularJs routing not working

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to work out a simple example for the angular routing but its not working (it is not getting redirected to the page i expect when i browse the root directory)

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head data-ng-app="MyApp">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/routing.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   Hello

    <ng-view></ng-view>
     <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT (routing.js)**

```
/// <reference path="angular.js" />

var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', [])

.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: '/Templates/dashboard.html',controller:'Mycontroller' })

    .otherwise({redirectTo :'/Templates/otherwise.html'})

});

function Mycontroller() {

}
```

I am running this from Visual studio and the root url am getting in the browser is localhost:3669/ and as per my angular routing i expect this to dispaly the dashboard.html but it is not and shows only the main html page (the code i have pasted)

Any help on this will be much appreciated

Comment: You routing.js should be defined after angular.js

Answer (score 4):

You are running your code before Angular! Place the `<script>` with your code after the `<script>` of Angular.

Answer (score 2):

Please remove '/' from '/Templates/dashboard.html' just use Templates/dashboard.html

```
$routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: 'Templates/dashboard.html',controller:'Mycontroller' })

.otherwise({redirectTo :'Templates/otherwise.html'})
```